# If I create a custom object tab with tab settings as "Default on" for system administrator profile and not include it any app?

Tags: custom-object, profile, system-admin, custom-tab

Now, I created a custom object and then created a custom tab for it, in that I selected default ON only for system admin profile, after that I did not include the tab in any of the applications. Now when I go to the sales application or any application for that matter and click on the more drop down option next to all the tabs on the right, the custom tab is not in the list but if I select personlize you nav bar option and go to "All tabs" and search for the tab I had created, I can see it in the list and add it to the nav bar from there.

1. The tab is directly visible to the Administrator in every application as it is set to default on and no need to explicitly include it in any of the applications.
2. The tab will only be visible to the Administrator in "All Tabs" unless it is included to any of the applications.
3. A tab cannot be set to default on if it is NOT included in any of the applications.

I feel the correct option should be the second one according to my logic.

Would love someone else's insight on this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question too much but hopefully this helps.

Tab settings specify whether a tab is visible in its associated app. They also determine whether a tab appears in the All Tabs page in Salesforce Classic and whether objects appear in the Lightning Experience App Launcher and navigation menus.

**Default Off**
The tab doesn’t appear in an app’s navigation bar, but it is available in the App Launcher in Lightning Experience and on the All Tabs page in Salesforce Classic.

Individual users can customize their display to make the tab visible in any app.

**Default On**
The tab appears in an app’s navigation bar. The tab is also available in the App Launcher in Lightning Experience and on the All Tabs page in Salesforce Classic.

Individual users can customize their display to hide the tab or make it visible in other apps.

**Tab Hidden**
The tab isn’t available in the App Launcher or the All Tabs page, isn’t visible in any app navigation, and is excluded from API responses.

> Check the settings of your App (Setup - Create - App - Edit Your app):
>
> App: Selected Tabs -> your tab is there App: Assign to Profiles ->
> target user profile is there Check the settings of the target user
> profile:
>
> Tab Settings: Cases -> Default On Standard Object Permissions: Cases
> -> Read Custom App Settings: your app -> Visible

Comment: Sorry, the third option was incorrect earlier.
I have edited it now, but it can't be correct right because a tab can be set to "default on" for a profile even if its not included in any of the applications.